# php rename() under windows returning error code 3

Tags: php, windows, wamp, file-rename

Ok - im stuck and its php rename() again!!! I am sure I have an error in the way I am describing the file path, and I am using file names with spaces '.' and ' ' to ensure I account for all filenaming variances.  So to my code that I am trying

```
    function GetFiles($dirName) {
    $root = scandir($dirName);
    foreach ($root as $value) {
        if ($value === '.' || $value === '..') {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_file("$dirName\\$value")) {
            $result[] = "$dirName\\$value";
            continue;
        }
        foreach (GetFiles("$dirName\\$value") as $value) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    function FileReorder($filename,$basedir){
            $filebase = basename($filename);
            $date = getdate(filectime($filename));
            if($date['mon'] < 10){$datem ='0'. $date['mon'];}
            $datey = $date['year'];
            $newPath = "$basedir\\$datey\\$datem";
            $newFileName = "$newPath\\$filebase";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $filhandle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        fclose($filhandle);
        sleep(1);
        $renamed = rename($filename, $newFileName);
    } else {
        $renamed = false;
    }
    if ($renamed) {
        printf('File Renamed: old-' . $filename . ' new-' . $newFileName . ' ');
    } else {
        printf('File Rename failed');
            return $renamed;

        }
    //entry point is here
        $startDir=$formpost['directory'];
        $files=  GetFiles($formpost['directory']);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
                $reodered = FileReorder($file, $startDir);
        }
```

So I would paste a string variable in like C:\Users\username\Pictures\my test
please note I am using spaces on purpose for debugging.

### Warning for Filereorder function (it returns FALSE)

> Warning: rename(C:\Users\user\Pictures\my test\2013-03-28 
>   14.36.13.jpg,C:\Users\user\Pictures\my test\2013\03\2013-03-28 14.36.13.jpg) [function.rename]: The system cannot find the path specified.
>   (code: 3) in C:\wamp\www\MediaOrganizer\fileTime.php on line 48

Any assistance would be appreciated.

---

Addendum 
After much reading I think this may be a win32 shell limitation - I am assuming the php rename function makes a low level call into the windows shell.  Windows shell doesnt support multiple '.' in the file name. Windows and NT do support it but not in the shell
You can test this by the fact you can directory list using dir in cmd shell but cant open a file from the command line.  if you refer to the file by its shorthand dose name that will work. Unfortunately this doesnt solve my problem - in fact I think it means php cannot rename files in the windows environment that contain multiple periods.

Comment: php explicitly states that there is no such file

Comment: it exists otherewise - $filhandle = fopen($filename,'r'); followed by    fclose($filhandle); would have errored out long before rename did. but to satisfy this I wrapped the fileopen down to the rename in a if(file_exists($filename) condition.

Comment: Additionally realpath($filename) === $filename

Comment: Were you able to solve that?

Comment: I havent revisited the issue in some time jayarjo but it may well have been a specific php version

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help this will be but this code works just fine using PHP CLI 5.3.22

```
<?php
    $from = 'D:\php_source\tst dir\my file.name.as.oddly as possible.txt';
    $to =   'D:\php_source\tst dir\my file.name.as.oddly as possible.22.33.44.txt';
    rename($from,$to);
?>
```